# facebook page access token issues

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to put a feed on a companies website from their FB page. The feed would only read in posts.  What is the most efficient way to maintain an access token for the feed?

Answer (score 1):

In order to establish this feed access, you can use Facebook's universal page RSS feed:

`https://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID_HERE&format=rss20`

Simply retrieve and parse the data accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: when I try using this address I get a Facebook Syndication Error that tells me that this feed URL is no longer valid.